# Android exception android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked

Tags: android

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to monitor the battery power. I referred [this](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) and my code is

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
}
```

}

and added this in my manifest

```
  <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It works but in the onReceive, intent doesn't has any value in it. And when I try to start an activity in onReceive, app stops and returns the following error.

```
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.example.batterycharging.Activity.MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.example.batterycharging.Activity.MainActivity$1@b7548490 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:756)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:551)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:800)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:787)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:781)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
        at com.example.suresh.batterycharging.Activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know how to do this. Can anyone please help me to detect the battery status. Thanks in advance.

Here is the MainActivity.java class

```
package com.example.batterycharging.Activity;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.suresh.batterycharging.R;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /*private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        //When Event is published, onReceive method is called
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            //Get Battery %
            int level = i.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            //Find the progressbar creating in main.xml
            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            //Set progress level with battery % value
            pb.setProgress(level);
            //Find textview control created in main.xml
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfield);
            //Set TextView with text
            tv.setText("Battery Level: " + Integer.toString(level) + "%");
        }

    };*/


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
//                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please check MainActivity.java line number 40...?? or post the line here

Comment: There is nothing in line no 40. Its just  a newline.

Comment: In onReceive() the intent not having any extra values in it.

Comment: @SureshKumar, where in the manifest did you add the receiver lines?

Comment: Yes I have added the receiver in the manifest file. See the above code.

Comment: But where in the manifest? Have you registered it twice perhaps?

Comment: I think you should clean your project and rebuild and test again, broadcast receiver registered using xml should not be leaking. If it does than this is very probably be a platform bug (but I don't think so, your code works fine on my emulator)

Answer (score 2):

You are registering a `BroadcastReceiver` at line 40 of `MainActivity`.

You need to `unregisterReceiver(...)` in `onPause()`.

You need to either register the `BroadcastReceiver` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file or with `registerReceiver(...)`. You shouldn't need to do both.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Knossos. I am not doing anything in my MainActivity. I am registering it in my manifest itselt.

Comment: So what is at line 40?

Comment: Nothing in their in line no 40. Its just a new line.

Comment: Double check that the code you are working on right now is the same as the code installed onto your device. Double check the logcat output matches what you have already shown us if it crashes again. The stacktrace you have shown is clearly shows that you are calling registerReceiver on line 40 of MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it will solve your issue but try to unregister before destroy.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new PowerConnectionReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);

    }
```

can you add these lines in onCreate() method

```
    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = this.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
```

and

At Last of your broad cast receiver for testing purpose.

```
Toast.makeText(context, isCharging+"/"+status+"/"+chargePlug+"/"+acCharge+"/"+usbCharge+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Raghavendra. I am not registering the receiver in my activity. Then how I can unregister it.

Comment: you are registering it in manifest like <receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">

Comment: I tried unregistering it in onPause but no luck. It still stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76173/discussion-between-suresh-kumar-and-raghavendra).

Answer (score 1):

You need to unregister the receiver you have registered in the Activity/Fragment. 
You should do it in the **onStop()** or **onDestroy()** method of your Activity/Fragment.

In an activity call :

```
unregisterReceiver(RECEIVER_NAME);
```

In a fragment call :

```
getActivity().unregisterReceiver(RECEIVER_NAME);
```

Also, it would be a good practice to check if your receiver is not null for unregistering it.